How many six-digit numbers, formed by using digits from $1$ to $6$ with repetititon, are divisible by 3？
The six-digit number can be formed by any number between $1$ and $6$. The digits can be repeated.
My question is how many six-digit numbers like this are divisible by $3$?
The answer is $2 \cdot 6^5$. I cannot understand how to deduce it.

Hint: pick the first five digits of the number, for example 54226 (there's nothing special about this one).  How many ways can you pick the sixth digit to make a multiple of three - that is, how many of 542261, 542262, 542263, 542264, 542265, 542266 are divisible by three?

I guess I get your point. I can randomly pick the first five digits of the number. For the six-digit number to be divisible by 3, the sum should be divisible by 3. And the only three cases for the sum of the first five digits mod 3 are 0, 1, 2. Under each of these 3 cases, for the last digit, I can find exactly 2 number to make the 6-digit number divible by 3. That contributes to the final answer $2*6^5$. Correct me if I am wrong. Thanks!

That's exactly right.

Thanks for the hint from [Michael].(https://math.stackexchange.com/users/173/michael-lugo)
I try to come up with a complete explanation for this question.
Firstly, one "theorem" we must know is that any number whose sum of digits is divisible by $3$ is divisible by $3$. Also, using the basic knowledge about mod operation, divisible by 3 is same as mod $3 = 0$.
e.g. $123$ is divisible by $3$ because its sum of digits is $1+2+3 = 6$, which is divisible by $3$.
Now we have a six-digit number, using the above "theorem", if the sum of its digits is divisible by 3. then the six-digit number will be divisible by 3.

We can think of the six-digit number as two parts. The first part is the first five digits, and the second part is the remaining one digit. Now the sum of the six digits can be divided into the sum of the first five digits adding the sixth digit.

As we all know, any number mod $3$, the result will be among $0,1,2$. Applying this to the first five digits, whatever digit we choose, its sum mod $3$ will always be among $0,1,2$.

To make sure the sum of the six digits divisible by 3, we need to make sure its sum mod $3$ is 0. 
case 1: sum of first five digits mod $3$ = 0.For the sixth digit, we can only choose 3 or 6 to make the six-digit number divisible by 3. 
case 2: sum of first five digits mod $3$ = 1. Now, only 2 or 5 applies. 
case 3: sum of first five digits mod $3$ = 2. Only 1 or 4 applies.

So, till now, we have found that no matter how we choose the first five digits, there are always and only two options for the sixth digit. So, now we can understand why the answer is $2*6^5$. $2$ stands for the option for the sixth digit and $6^5$ stands for all the possible different first five digits we can have.



You can calculate number of all numbers, which consist of digits from $1$ to $6$: $N= 6^6$. The number of such numbers, which is divisible by $3$ is equal to $N_3=[6^6/3]=[2\cdot 6^5]=2\cdot 6^5$, where $[\cdot]$ is floor function. The reason is that consecutive numbers divisible by 3 go in increments of 3.

There are $6^6$ combinations of six digit numbers that can be formed by the digits 1 through 6.  One third of them will be divisible by 3. (Because you can increase or decrease any of the digits by 1, the modulus of a 1/3 of the numbers will be $0$, 1/3 will be 1 and 1/3 will be 2.)
$6^6 = 6\times6^5$, so 1/3 of that will be $2\times6^5$
